# List<String> to string back to List in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have stored a `java.util.List` of Strings  such as

```
[data1,data2,data3,data3,data7]
```

in a String.

How can I convert it back to a List of String, knowing that some values are just empty ?

Update:
I am not able to convert implicitly. Getting error cannot cast string to string[]. Also tried converting to list. No success.

Update2:
, cannot be used to split because the data also contains ,

Update 3:
[/Simplify.do, action, temp,test,data]
Data with , but without spaces is a single data.

Comment: Show what you have done and where do you get confusion

Comment: Do you wish to keep the empty values?

Comment: @AHungerArtist No I dont want the empty values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I am understanding the questions correctly, and your data has a delimiter of a comma.

```
//if you have the brackets remaining and don't want them, remove them
data = data.replace("[","").replace("]","");


String data = "data1,data2,data3";
//You would put the second parameter as -1 if you want to keep any trailing blank values 
List<String> smapleData= Arrays.asList(data.split(",",-1));
//or if you don't want to keep trailing blanks
List<String> sampleDataTwo = Arrays.asList(data.split(","));
```

that would bring it back to a list of strings.

Comment: You will have to use the [two parameters version of `String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) with a negative `limit` if you want to keep the trailing empty values.

Comment: The brackets are also present in my string

Comment: Is there no implicit way to convert back to list or even string array would be great

Comment: You need to be way more specific on what you want to do vignesh. This answer started out as my guessing the question and then answering it. You have brackets, so I removed them, you don't say if you want to keep trailing blanks so I gave you both options. And you didn't fully specify your delimiter so I assumed it was a comma and included that. I think the answer is pretty solid from what I gleaned from your questions. If you don't think so then perhaps a few clarifications are in order.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono , cannot be used as split regex because data contains ,

Comment: @vignesh , Then you need to tell me what the delimiter is, or provide sample data so we can figure out how to split it.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono Just now realized , and space can be used as a regex. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below methodology for your query:

**Initial Declaration**:

```
  String myNewList=new String();
  String data = "data1,data2,data3";
```

Firstly split your values based on the comma which you can use as a delimiter

```
 myNewList=data.split(",");
```

And then pass it to a new list that will you give your desired result that is list of strings.

```
List<String> myList= Arrays.asList(myNewList);
```